# updating a useState array in a functional component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to transform a class component in a functional component but I have the feeling that the useState(in a functional component) and the setState(from a class component) are not really working the same way.

Here is the code in the class component that is working well:

```
// Load images
      for (var i = 1; i <= imagesCount; i++) {
        const image = await tipMyMeme.methods.images(i).call()
        this.setState({
          images: [...this.state.images, image]
        })
      }
    
      this.setState({ loading: false})
```

And here the same code in a functional component that is not working:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= imagesCount; i++) {
    const image = await tipMyMeme.methods.images(i).call()
                                    
    setImages(images => [...images, image]);
                                    
 }
console.log("images",images)
                               
 if (images.length==imagesCount) 
{
    setLoading(false)  
}
```

In the console.log(images), I am noticing that the array is staying empty. Is there here a real difference in the way a class and a functional component work?

What I am trying to achieve is to load a list of images and send them as props in the sub component. The process of loading is working well, for exemple, if I put a console log under const image, I can see each image. What is not working I feel is the process of creating a state array of images with setImages.

Comment: `If i put for exemple a console.log(images)` Where are you putting that log statement? If you're putting it right after `setImages(images => [...images, image])`, then it can only ever show the old value. If you want to verify that the component rerendered, then put your log statement at the top level of your component

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what kind of issue you're running into? Setting state here might be a red herring, and the real issue could be with rendering

Comment: Can you post the entire `class`?

Comment: I edit the code to add the console log.

Comment: `useState` and `setState` are both async, so it would make sense that you're seeing an empty array. What is `loading` doing? I don't think this can be diagnosed as is. Try updating your snippets with the full (minimal) components or consider making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you have put that second snippet directly into the body of your functional component without wrapping it inside a `useEffect`, then you will certainly not achieve the result you are after. Please update your snippets to show where they are being used wrt your component